# NVD3: Have labels at certain tick values at the top of the graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, nvd3.js

I am using NVD3 to draw a graph that uses an ordinal scale on the x axis for dates. I also have a "focus graph" under it to highlight a specific region to display. To automatically update the ticks that are displayed, I use the tickValues() property.

I want to have label on specific dates at the top of the graph. My solution for this was to create another x axis, but above the the graph, plot the same data, but with a 0 height, and then use tickValues() to set the position of the labels. However, the labels don't show up on the top axis. Is there a solution or alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess using a secondary x axis is fine. I forgot to remove the line setting the domain property for my secondary axis. When I removed that, it scaled just like my primary axis :)